# How do I import a dll-module written in C++ to Python using PyBind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I've been having trouble getting pybind11 to work the way described [here](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/basics.html#windows).

I was able to build the example DLL in Visual Studio 2019 but I don't understand how to actually get a Python script to recognize the module using an 'import' statement.

This the test module written in C++ (compiles without any issues):

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}


PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; // optional module docstring

    m.def("add", &add, "A function which adds two numbers");
```

This is my test Python script which attempts to call the module:

```
import example
print(example.add(1,2))
```

The above simply fails to identify the module - i.e. "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'example'"

I've placed my Python script in the same folder as the DLL build (containing various files - .obj, .iobj,.lib etc. )

I'm running Python 3.8 on Windows 10 if it matters.

I've been bashing my head against Boost.Python all day before finally finding pybind11 but I can't get it to work!!

Comment: What is the name of your DLL? Try to rename it `example.pyd`.

Comment: Oh wow that worked.... thank you so much. I had it just as 'example.dll.' My brain is so cooked from trying to get Boost.Python to work... big thanks...

Comment: Python doesn't know what a DLL is, and will only recognize PYD files. And yeah, Boost.Python can be uneasy to setup, but once you get it right is so much more powerful than Pybind11. I will admit, I haven't had a look at the later for quite a long time so I'm not sure of its evolution and current state but what I like about Boost, is that it is an entire suite offering so much more! And except for built-in STL support Pybind11 didn't have much more to offer..